# Error on using copy Command in Postgres (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "")

Tags: postgresql

I have a CSV file from which I am trying to use Postgres `COPY` command in order to populate a table from that CSV file. One of the table columns `NEXT_VISIT` is of a date data_type. Some of the corresponding fields in the CSV file which are supposed to go into this date column have null values.

The Copy command am running is like so:

```
COPY "VISIT_STAGING_TABLE" from E'C:\\Users\\Sir Codealot\\Desktop\\rufijihdss-2007-2010\\rufijihdss\\VISIT_TEST.CSV' CSV HEADER
```

When I run this command I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY VISIT_STAGING_TABLE, line 2, column NEXT_VISIT: ""

********** Error **********
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
SQL state: 22007
Context: COPY VISIT_STAGING_TABLE, line 2, column NEXT_VISIT: ""
```

How can I run the copy command and get Postgres to accept that some of the fields in the CSV file corresponding to `NEXT_VISIT` have values `""`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, and what solved it for me was to use the statement `WITH NULL ''`. It is important *not to have a space between the apostrophes*.

I originally used the statement `WITH NULL ' '` and got the same error message you did (ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH NULL").

But when I eliminated the space between the apostrophes it worked.

Answer (score 14):

Add `WITH NULL AS ''` to your command (*COPY expects NULLs to be represented as "\N" (backslash-N) by default*).

```
COPY "VISIT_STAGING_TABLE" from E'C:\\Users\\Sir Codealot\\Desktop\\rufijihdss-2007-2010\\rufijihdss\\VISIT_TEST.CSV' WITH CSV HEADER NULL AS ''
```

More details here: [postgresql COPY](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY)

Comment: ok I have tried that option: COPY "VISIT_STAGING_TABLE" from E'C:\\Users\\Sir Codealot\\Desktop\\rufijihdss-2007-2010\\rufijihdss\\VISIT_TEST.CSV' CSV HEADER WITH NULL AS ''                        and I get the error :ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH NULL"

Comment: `WITH` must come before any option & after the file path. See my edit.

Comment: tried that too:COPY "VISIT_STAGING_TABLE" from E'C:\\Users\\Sir Tumaini Kilimba\\Desktop\\rufijihdss-2007-2010\\rufijihdss\\VISIT_TEST.CSV' WITH NULL AS '""' CSV HEADER, but that now gives me the error ERROR:  "CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification"... also tried COPY "VISIT_STAGING_TABLE" from E'C:\\Users\\Sir Tumaini Kilimba\\Desktop\\rufijihdss-2007-2010\\rufijihdss\\VISIT_TEST.CSV' WITH NULL AS "" CSV HEADER (no single quotes around the double quotes) and get the error ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"....

Comment: Hamza,The link you have provided me with (http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY) confirms to me that POSTGRES cannot deal with what I am asking. Here is an excerpt from that page on that link : "NULL behavior is counter-intuitive
    WITH NULL AS '""' will not insert a null when empty quotes are encountered, anything quoted is non-null, and this argument does not short-circuit that behavior."