# Django with Postgresql Full Text Search Date and Time Input Type Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

Here is my current code:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
   def with_documents(self):
       vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A') + \
                SearchVector('slug', weight='B') + \
                SearchVector('content', weight='C') + \
                SearchVector('category', weight='D') + \
                SearchVector(StringAgg('tags__slug', delimiter=' ')) + \
                SearchVector('chron_date')
       if SearchVector('chron_date') == "":
           SearchVector('chron_date') == None
       if SearchVector('clock') == "":
           SearchVector('clock') == None
       return self.get_queryset().annotate(document=vector)
```

Here is my error:

```
invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 1: ...| to_tsvector(COALESCE("ktab_entry"."chron_date", ''))) AS "...
```

I first got this error on the prior version of my code, at which time I followed the advice posted here: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-invalid-input-syntax-for-type-date-error-while-executing-the-query by adding the two if clauses at the end, but that didn't work. I have seen this answer on SO: [Error on using copy Command in Postgres (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045402/error-on-using-copy-command-in-postgres-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-type-da) but there are no spaces in my quotes. This question on SO [invalid input syntax for type date: "" in django, postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786800/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-date-in-django-postgresql) has no answer. 
FWIW, there actually is a value in both the chron_date and clock fields: 2017-11-02 & 14:41:00 respectively. I already tried changing datestyle() to no effect. I also added null=True on the models but still get the same error.

Django 1.11.5, Postgresql 9.4, Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I am told PG FTS does not yet handle dates or times.